# Bootstrap 5. Как убрать у img отступы справа и слева? 12px

Tags: bootstrap

```
<main class="d-flex align-items-center text-center">
    <section>
        <div class="container-fluid pt-5 bg-light">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <!-- <h1 class="">Строительство домов, бань, коттеджей из дерева под ключ!</h1> -->
                    <img src="img/gora/kudyk-02.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <p class="fs-5">Более 25 лет в работе, строительно любой сложности. <strong> Построим бани, веранды, коттеджи или даже крепости.</strong> <br><br> Эту крепость построили мы!</p>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </section>
  </main>
```

Comment: явно ведь ещё стилей не хватает. пожалуйста, дополните вопрос, нажав [edit]

Comment: стилей вообще нет

Comment: откройте devtools, посмотрите на стили у col-12, там паддинги, обнулите их, если вам надо, но bootstrap так работает

Comment: Да, я супер даун, спасибо. Просто прописал p-0 у  <div class="col-12">